# How to call upon and execute a method

Tags: java, methods, playing-cards

I have a question that may be very basic, but I cant seem to find it on stack (and what I do find is very complicated) so I'm very sorry if it's already out there somewhere.

I'm writing a card game in java, and I want to move the piece of code that draws a new card into a separate method, so that I may call on it whenever, instead of having the same piece of code appear again and again whenever I need it.

The only problem is I don't know what type of method to use or how to call on it, since it's not going to return anything, just do a bunch of code.

Here is the piece of my code that draws a card, if that helps to show what I'm aiming to do.

```
if (event.getSource() == hit && endOfRound == false) {
    Continue = true;
    while (Continue == true) //If the random number has been drawn before, loop the random number generator again
    {
        cardID = (int) RandomNumber.GetRandomNumber(52);
        if (cardsLeft[cardID] == true) //If a new card is drawn, continue normally
        {
            Continue = false; //Stop the loop that draws a new card
            cardsLeft[cardID] = false; //save that the card was drawn
            stay.setBackground(Color.green);

            plyrSum += BlackJack.value(cardID); //add value to sum
            plyrSumLabel.setText("Your sum: " + plyrSum); //display new sum
            cardLabel[plyrCardCounter].setIcon(cardImage[cardID]); //Display card

            plyrCardCounter++;
            if (cardID >= 48) //record how many aces are in the hand so the program knows how many times it can reduce the sum. 
                plyrAceCounter++;
            while (plyrSum > 21 && plyrAceCounter > 0) //If bust, reduce the value of an ace by 10 (from 11 to 1). 
            {
                plyrSum -= 10;
                plyrSumLabel.setText("Your sum: " + plyrSum);
                plyrAceCounter--;
            }

            if (plyrSum > 21) //Automatically end the round if someone  busts (player)
            {
                stay.doClick();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Decomposing a complex procedure into a series of smaller, separate, and logically distinct steps is, generally, always a good idea.  In object-oriented languages like Java, this should happen as a natural consequence of your object model.  I notice that you are writing a card game, so it seems that a natural domain object would be `Card`, yet it does not seem that your project has an object-oriented abstraction for cards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare a method **drawCard()** that returns void. Now copy the block inside *if* and paste it inside the method.
Then rewrite the *if* part:

```
if (event.getSource() == hit && endOfRound == false) drawCard();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but what do i call the method? public static void? Because that doesnt seem to work. (error message: Syntax error on token "void", @ expected) What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Thats so strange, because when I go through it and I feel sure that I've done exacly that, yet somehow I get another error message saying "Multiple markers at this line
 - drawCard cannot be resolved to a 
  type
 - Syntax error on token "void", new 
  expected"

Comment: Nvm I solved it, I had just pasted it in the wrong place.